# Closing stdout required for wait on sub process to finish?

Tags: bash, process, wait

I have a question from https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/106

Have a look at this code:

```bsh
exec > >(tee myfile)
pspid=$!

# ... stuff ...
echo "A"
cat file
echo "B"
# end stuff

# All done.  Close stdout so the proc sub will terminate, and wait for it.
exec >&-
wait $pspid


# what happens if we delete line exec >&- ?
# what if ...stuff... do not finish before >&- ?
```

My first question is why do we need `exec >&-` here? What happens if we delete it? I'm guessing deleting `exec >&-` will cause `wait $pspid` to wait indefinitely.

Since `tee myfile` runs in background asynchronously I would expect `stuff` will be processed out of order. So my second question is, what if any of `stuff` do not finish before `>&-`?

Comment: "stuff will be processed out of order" does not follow from "`tee myfile` runs in background asynchronously"

Comment: @muru `tee myfile` won't wait for first batch of input to be processed before accepting next input.

Comment: What processing?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/106 it says "Because there is a background job that has to read and process all our output before we see it, this introduces some asynchronous delay. "

Comment: i got confused by that but now i know that every line runs in order as expected. thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, in the part you quote, the preceding code writes to both stderr and stdout, but both are sent to tee. However, the streams are otherwise independent, and get flushed independently. So it's possible that you wrote to stderr before stdout, but tee might receive stdout before stderr. In your question's example, you're always writing to stdout, so everything will be in order.